# nextJS 13 middleware. (NextJS documentation is not enough)

Tags: next.js, middleware, next.js13

I am learning about NextJS middleware, but the issue is that there is not enough sources to learn about it or the sources are outdated.
If you can explain about any one of these, then it will be a very big help.
**If you want, you can add things from your side too.** I will try to tell what I understood about it.

1.**NextResponse.next()**

Its like **next()** we have in express, which allows us to move on to the next middleware or the API end-point. So, it allows us to reach the end-point of the API.

2.**NextResponse**

1. When **NextResponse** is used (**NextResponse.redirect(), etc**) to send a response, then
   response is sent back to client side, while the API never reaches its
   end-point.
2. Why **NextResponse( redirect )** refreshes the page??
3. Can you explain what **rewrite** is?
4. **Cookies**

- Can we set the expiration for the cookies and how can we send cookies
  back from middleware?

5. Response

Consider the following response from the middleware

```
  return new NextResponse(
    JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "authentication failed" }),
    { status: 401, headers: { "content-type": "application/json" } }
  );
```

When this response is send back, then the JSON data is shown in the whole webpage (like hitting the url- http://localhost:3000/api/hello ), while we have to extract data from other endpoints response.

like (ex-  /api/auth/login)

```
res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: 'authentication failed' })
```

I might be wrong, so feel free to correct me.
Anything will be helpful.